# How can I create zip file with the date in its name?

Tags: bash, zip

In the command-line, how can I create a zip file from a directory, whose name would be the current date?

I can use `zip -r name dir`, but how give it the date for a name?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By slipping the `date` command into the filename:

```
zip -r "archive-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" file1 file2 file3 file4
```

That just does year-month-day but you can use times, weeks, etc if that suits you more. You can read more about the substitution strings in `man date`.

Comment: for date with time: zip -r "archive-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").zip" file1 file2 file3 file4